# SQL Server Removing Duplicate Rows & Managing Keys

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, primary-key, primary-key-design

I have two tables as shown below.

The **Transaction Table** is a table representing a sales event between a Buyer and a Supplier. The ... in the table represents other columns such as TransactionDate, Store Information, etc.

The **Contact Table** is a table representing the Buyer and a Supplier's information such as name & home addresss etc.

Right now the two tables share a one-to-one relationship where BuyerID = ContactID and SellerID = ContactID.

I'm populating this table with a python script so the answer could be in python, SQL, or both.

Current State

**Transaction Table**

| TransactionID (pk) | ... | BuyerID | SellerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11914 |  | 11914 Buyer | 11914 Seller |
| 11915 |  | 11915 Buyer | 11915 Seller |
| 11916 |  | 11916 Buyer | 11916 Seller |

**Contact Table**

| ContactID (pk) | ... | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11914 Buyer |  | Mike | Doe |
| 11914 Seller |  | Janet | Myers |
| 11915 Buyer |  | Janet | Myers |
| 11915 Seller |  | Mike | Doe |
| 11916 Buyer |  | Dave | Dirk |
| 11916 Seller |  | Janet | Myers |

What I'd like to do is remove the repetitive rows in the **Contact Table** and make the table relationships a one-to-many. Additionally if for example Janet Myers changes her last name, there would be be a new addition to the Contact Table despite all of the other columns staying the same. i.e. ignoring the ContactID column, there shouldn't be two identical rows in the ContactTable.

Future State

**Transaction Table**

| TransactionID (pk) | ... | BuyerID | SellerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11914 |  | 06dfe636-4408-4abe-b902-b1ac6aab9849 | 58e5c2f7-d0ef-4129-a5a8-e17efaee0a1d |
| 11915 |  | 58e5c2f7-d0ef-4129-a5a8-e17efaee0a1d | 06dfe636-4408-4abe-b902-b1ac6aab9849 |
| 11916 |  | ab99de1f-a714-4709-9a1e-f3a143b279d2 | 58e5c2f7-d0ef-4129-a5a8-e17efaee0a1d |

**Contact Table**

| ContactID (pk) | ... | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06dfe636-4408-4abe-b902-b1ac6aab9849 |  | Mike | Doe |
| 58e5c2f7-d0ef-4129-a5a8-e17efaee0a1d |  | Janet | Myers |
| ab99de1f-a714-4709-9a1e-f3a143b279d2 |  | Dave | Dirk |

My first thought to solve this would be to create the ContactID out of a hash of all the other columns.

```
sha256(json.dumps(contactDict.encrypt('utf-8'))).hexdigest()
```

Then I'd use a `MERGE` statement to add the contact if it the ContactID hash didn't already exist in the table. I think this would work, however I'm having second thoughts risking a hash collision with financial data.

Other than a hash, my other thought would be a `MERGE` statement but with around 15 columns in the `ON` clause I thought that'd be very low performance.

Comment: is the last row of your Contact table being Janet a mistake/typo or an example of your data quality? (ie, is [number] expected to uniquely identify an individual and the suffix just calling out repetition?)

Comment: Janet was involved with every transaction shown, either as a Buyer or Seller. That is why Janet appears multiple times in the Contacts Table. My Goal is to only have her in the Contacts Table once, and each transaction reference the same one Janet entry.